# UV for 20 different parts

Tags: modeling

So I have this model that is like made from 20 different parts. I want one big UV for all the parts but I want them to be separated, I don't want to glue the model and then cut it again into separate parts. Is it possible?

Comment: Many objects, but you don't want to join?  You can use multi-object editing.  Select all the objects, tab to edit, select all verts of all objects, u->unwrap or whatever.

Comment: thanks. btw. i'm using 2.79b for some reasons ( this game doesn't have a 3.0 export so I'm forced to use and old blender version ).

Comment: Yeah, that turns out to be relevant, no multi-object editing in 2.79.  Should be able to unwrap in a later version and copy/paste back into 2.79-- possibly, as the target of a data transfer for original object-- but untested.  There were also "texture atlas" addons that could do the same thing, but I'm not sure how much luck you'll have finding addons intended for 2.79.